# Context is returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, 2d-context-api

Form

```
import { useState, createContext } from "react";
import { data } from "../../../../data";

export const peopleContext = createContext();


export default function Form() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(data);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!name) {
      alert("Please Provide Name Value");
      return;
    }
    addPerson();
    setName("");
  };
  const addPerson = () => {
    const fakeId = Date.now();
    const newPerson = { id: fakeId, name };
    setPeople([...people, newPerson]);
  };
  console.log(people)
  return (
    <peopleContext.Provider value={{ people }}>
      <section>
        <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="form-row">
            <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">
              name
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              id="name"
              className="form-input"
              value={name}
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <button className="btn btn-block" type="submit">
            submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </section>
    </peopleContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Index

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import List from './List';
import Form, { peopleContext } from './Form';

const LowerStateChallenge = () => {

 
const l = useContext(peopleContext)
console.log(l)

  return (
    <section>
      <Form />
      {/* <List people={people} /> */}
    </section>
  );
};

export default LowerStateChallenge;
```

I have created  a form Component from which I need to pass people state to LowerStateChallengeComponent, but the context that I have defined in Form is always returning undefined in the parent component.

people state should be passed to the parent component, but the peopleContext is always returning undefined. What did I miss?

Comment: Similar to props, context can only pass data from a parent component to a child component, not from a child to a parent. Usually when this happens you should [lift state up and pass it down](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components#lifting-state-up-by-example)

Answer (score 0):

As @Nicholas Tower mentioned, you can use [lifting-state-up](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components#lifting-state-up-by-example)

e.g.

`App.tsx`:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Form from './Form';
import { List } from './List';

export const App = () => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!name) {
      alert('Please Provide Name Value');
      return;
    }
    addPerson();
    setName('');
  };
  const addPerson = () => {
    const fakeId = Date.now();
    const newPerson = { id: fakeId, name };
    setPeople([...people, newPerson]);
  };
  console.log(people);

  return (
    <div>
      <Form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        onChange={(nextName) => setName(nextName)}
        value={name}
      />
      <List people={people} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

`Form.tsx`:

```
import { FormEvent } from 'react';

export type FormProps = {
  onSubmit(e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void;
  value: string;
  onChange(value: string): void;
};
export default function Form({ onSubmit, value, onChange }: FormProps) {
  return (
    <section>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className="form-row">
          <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">
            name
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            className="form-input"
            value={value}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <button className="btn btn-block" type="submit">
          submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
}
```

`List.tsx`:

```
import { useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import React from 'react';

export const List = ({ people }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {people.map((p) => (
        <li key={p.id}>{p.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-olavxm?file=src%2FList.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used "Context" in wrong direction from child to parent. Context also work as props from parent to child. so, you should createContext in LowerStateChallenge and useContext in form component.

for example you can refer :- https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext